# windows 11 network connections to local network

Tags: networking, windows-11

We cant reach any of our devices in the same network and they can't reach our new windows 11 computer.

Pings do work fine, but http requests, curl and other requests do not.

- I tried updating the network card driver ... no success.
- I reinitialized the network cards ... no success.
- I completely turned off the firewall ... no success.

The other devices can reach each other, just this new windows 11 computer doesn't.

Pings can reach the machine:

[image]

But e.g. curl does not:

```
C:\Users\username>curl http://192.168.0.163:5000/
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.0.163 port 5000 after 2051 ms: Connection refused
```

In Browser:

[image: When Running in Browser]

Localhost does work ... and the server is running:
[image: Server is Running]

```
C:\Users\username>curl http://localhost:5000/
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

I Honestly don't know what the problem is.
I asked the Microsoft Support, but they were no help at all.

Comment: For Windows 11 (I am using it) the version should be Pro, wireless connections must be Private, and then set Network Discovery, File and Print Sharing and Password Protected sharing all ON.  I connect freely between Windows 10 and 11 and between 11 and Linux.  So Windows 11 connects and shares well.

Comment: @John I have Windows 11 Home, my Ethernet connection is private and the other told settings are on too ...

Comment: You may wish to upgrade to Pro.   As I noted, Windows 11 (Pro) connects very well. Make sure your Windows 11 Firewall is set to default.

Comment: @John the Upgrade to Windows 11 Pro did the Job :) thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Windows 11 (I am using it) the version should be Pro, wireless connections must be Private, and then set Network Discovery, File and Print Sharing and Password Protected sharing all ON.

I connect freely between Windows 10 and 11 and between 11 and Linux. So Windows 11 connects and shares well. –

**You may wish to upgrade to Pro. As I noted, Windows 11 (Pro) connects very well.** Make sure your Windows 11 Firewall is set to default.

Now you (@OP) said that upgrading to Pro did the trick, then this is the answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

The Computer could be accessed after upgrading to Windows 11 Pro. Even with a running Firewall.